# How do I create a custom ListBoxItem with C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am learning C# and WPF. Now I want to make a customized ListBoxItem. With my own style. Containing some TextBlocks and a Image.
How do I achieve that?

I've tried to derive a Class from ListBoxItem but that dosn't work.
I also created a Style with ControleTemplate but I can't figure out how I can change the Text property of the TextBlocks inside the Template.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">            
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">     
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Name="test" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Margin="0,2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="media/pictures/noImage.png"/>
                                </StackPanel.Background>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="lbl_Heading" Text="HowToAccessThisProperty" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="lbl_Description" Text="HowToAccessThisProperty" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="lbl_FurtherInfo" Text="HowToAccessThisProperty" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at MSDN [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates)

Comment: Please explain in more detail exactly what you are trying to do with the ListView item. 99% of the time in WPF, we customize listview/listbox/etc. items using the ContentTemplate via the `ItemTemplate` property of the ListView/ListBox/whatever, not the control's Template. Where is the text for those TextBlocks supposed to be coming from? Are you sure you want to eliminate default highlighting behavior?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am trying to create a ListView item with a picture on the left side and a heading and two more lines where some more information about the item, which should be opened by double clicking it, is shown. The text and also the image comes from an SQL server. Actually I don't want do eliminate the default highlighting behavior. May you give a short example about ContentTemplate?

Comment: That sounds like the ContentTemplate. Easy. Now: How are you populating this ListView? What are you putting in it and how are you putting it there? "SQL" isn't an answer. An answer might be: "I'm binding ItemsSource to this (shows code) collection property of this class (shows code) containing this item class (shows code)", or "I'm assigning this DataTable with these columns (shows names and types of every column in the DataTable) to ItemsSource in my code behind". Please add this information to your question. It'll be unreadable in a comment. Thanks.